# Functional UI Design Patterns for Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle-apex

Are there any Functional UI (usability or UX) design patterns for Oracle Application Express development? Simple flows, best practices in information UIs layout, validation, skinning or rendering and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Oracle is not known for putting much emphasis on UX, so APEX-specific resources are scarce. A few suggestions:

Skinning can be done by downloading new Themes. While there's nowhere near as many themes as something like Wordpress, a Google search for "custom oracle apex themes" is still worth a try.

[Smashing Magazine's guide to web forms](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/08/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/) is relevant and extremely valuable to any APEX developer. There's no harm in drawing inspiration from non-APEX web apps, as the design principles are generally the same regardless of the development framework.

Don't be afraid to get into the HTML and CSS of the template and tinker around to make it prettier/more usable.

Comment: FYI - update: Doesn't indeed appear to be formal user experience website about APEX published on OTN or elsewhere. However, in APEX 4.2 there is set of packaged applications (productivity apps as well as sample apps). These apps common UI design patterns were developed using best practices and coding standards. ee also the following collateral available on OTN, such as the presentation on Responsive Web Design with APEX:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-presentations-1866619.html